# I can't figure out what this iOS element is for xcode

Tags: ios, iphone

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzLyL.jpg

I am thinking of adding one of these ui elements to my app but for some reason, I can't find the name of it online. All I see are alerts. Does anyone know what they are called? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are called UIActionSheets, here is the link to the [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try UIActionSheet? that is what it looks like